# Can't convert byte[] to BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmap, arrays

I've got images taken from a mobile app that I need to convert to a `BitmapImage`. All the the images taken are converted to a `byte[]` and stored in SQL Server.

I then want to retrieve that image and display it in a `Image` control in WPF. Here is my conversion from byte[] to BitmapImage:

```
private static BitmapImage LoadImage(byte[] imageData)
{
    if (imageData == null || imageData.Length == 0) return null;
    var image = new BitmapImage();
    using (var mem = new MemoryStream(imageData))
    {
        mem.Position = 0;
        image.BeginInit();
        image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        image.UriSource = null;
        image.StreamSource = mem;
        image.EndInit(); //Error exception here.
    }
    image.Freeze();
    return image;
}
```

I receive an error at the `EndInit()` line as shown above.

> No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found.

I call the `LoadImage()` method and like this:

```
MyCollection.Add(new ImageItems
{
    Id = image.Id,
    ImageData = LoadImage(image.TruckImg),
    DateTaken = image.DateTaken
});
```

The thing is I know that the byte[] `image.TruckImg` contains a valid image because when I attach that exact same image to an Email, the image gets displayed in Gmail correctly.

The email attachment code:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(image.TruckImg);
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(memoryStream, filename, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg));
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix my error above? Do I need to set specific headers for my BitmapImage to work? If I do, then how can that exact same byte[] `image.TruckImg` get displayed in Gmail correctly when I receive the mailed image...

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: The error message "No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found" is a clear indication that the byte array does not conatin a valid encoded image buffer, i.e. no JPEG, PNG, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I do not understand that I can send that that exact same byte[] as an email attachment to myself and it displays correctly as a .jpg image in my browser?

Comment: Yes, it's added to my conversion code above: `image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;`

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just tried it without it and I still get the same error. ;(

Comment: FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46

Comment: I guess there must be something wrong with your imageData. I've just tried to read a jpg file, convert it to `byte[]` and then using  your `LoadImage` method and works just fine...

Comment: @Pikoh Thanks for the comment! Yes the method works perfectly fine when I take smaller quality pictures from the mobile app (about 100 x 100 pixels), but only gives me this issue as soon as I set the dimensions upwords to about 1000 x 1000 pixels.

Comment: I've just tried with a 1998 x 1998 pìxel jpg and it also works fine. So what i think is that if it works with smaller images, the problem must be that they are being croped when saved to database or when readed to your image object. I would check that (e.g. checking the size of the buffer)

Comment: Will it help if I send someone the full byte[] with the image data in it?

Comment: Your ImageData is of type BitmapImage I believe?

Comment: @adminSoftDK The code wouldn't compile if it's not BitmapImage or one of its base classes. But that doesn't matter, because quite obviously the code is OK. The problem here is the source buffer, i.e. an encoded JPEG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the issue was sending the `byte[]` as a string over email. Somehow copying the whole string out of the database into the clipboard and sending it over email corrupts the image. Hope this helps someone out there that makes the same simple mistakes as me! :P